# Storing doubles into a 2D array

Tags: java

I'm having trouble storing numbers from a text file into a 2 dimensional array.  The first number represents the number of rows and the second number represents the number of columns.The values from the text file are:

```
3 3 
13.3 14 
9.9 1.7
0.343 2 6.44234
0.1234 798
```

It's successfully storing the first 2 numbers as the rows and columns, but gives me this output after running:

```
3
3
Error discovered at 0,0: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
Error discovered at 0,1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
Error discovered at 0,2: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
Error discovered at 1,0: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error discovered at 1,1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error discovered at 1,2: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
Error discovered at 2,0: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
Error discovered at 2,1: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
Error discovered at 2,2: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

I'm not sure what the issue is but here is the code I am using:

```
public class twoDArray 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    String filename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the file name: ");
    File file = new File(filename);
    try 
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        inputFile.close();
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File does not exist", "error", 1);
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    int ROW_SIZE = 0;
    int COLUMN_SIZE = 0;
    double[][] TEST_ARRAY = new double[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE]; 
    loadArray(filename, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE, TEST_ARRAY);

public static void loadArray(String file, int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE, double[][] TEST_ARRAY) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        ROW_SIZE = inputFile.nextInt();
        COLUMN_SIZE = inputFile.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(ROW_SIZE);
    System.out.println(COLUMN_SIZE);
     for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <  COLUMN_SIZE; j++) {
                try {
                    if (inputFile.hasNextDouble()){
                        TEST_ARRAY[i][j] = inputFile.nextDouble();
                    }
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Error discovered at " + i + "," + j + ": " + e);
                }
            }
     }

    inputFile.close();

}
}
```

Any help or guidance would be highly appreciated as I've already spent 7+ hours on debugging and trying to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ROW_SIZE = 0;
int COLUMN_SIZE = 0;
double[][] TEST_ARRAY = new double[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];
```

`ROW_SIZE` and `COLUMN_SIZE` are both 0 at this point. It's allocating a 0x0 array. You need to delay calling `new` until after you've read in the two sizes. Or you need to read the sizes earlier. One of the two.

Comment: It gives me an error, If they're not initialized. I pass the arguments to the loadArray method, and it's printing out that's storing the first 2 values as the row and column of the 2D of the array, but its giving an error storing the rest of the values into the array.

Comment: as mentioned already by John, your array is initialized with 0 length in both dimensions, therefore it cannot store any information in either dimension, leading to out of bounds exception.  You need to initialize your array with the maximum length necessary.  Move

`double[][] TEST_ARRAY = new double[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE]; `

to after 

`while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        ROW_SIZE = inputFile.nextInt();
        COLUMN_SIZE = inputFile.nextInt();
    }`

Comment: @JonathanNiu deleting the 0s in the dimensions and moving the Array helped, thank you.